# What date do I need to leave Europe?

Tags: visas

I entered Europe with a USA passport on May 3rd for a 90-day stay. I am wondering what exact date I have to leave Europe. How do I determine my exact cut off date?

Comment: Count 90 days including your arrival & departure days?

Comment: In the answers in the 'Duplicate link' there are at least two calculators where you can enter your arrival date and get a last departure date. But be careful and do not leave it on the last day, keep a day or so extra in case your flight is delayed or postponed by more than a few hours.